# compiler ignores operator new allocation

Tags: c++, g++, new-operator

I am programming a 512 bits integer in C++.
For the integer, I allocate memory from the heap using the `new` keyword, but the compiler (g++ version 8.1 on MINGW) seems to wrongfully optimize that out.
i.e compiler commands are:

`g++ -Wall -fexceptions -Og -g -fopenmp -std=c++14  -c main.cpp -o main.o`

`g++ -o bin\Debug\cs.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -O0 -lgomp`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <omp.h>

constexpr unsigned char arr_size = 16;
constexpr unsigned char arr_size_half = 8;
void exit(int);

struct uint512_t{
    uint32_t * bytes;
    uint512_t(uint32_t num){
        //The line below is either (wrongfully) ignored or (wrongfully) optimized out
        bytes = new(std::nothrow) uint32_t[arr_size];
        if(!bytes){
            std::cerr << "Error - not enough memory available.";
            exit(-1);
        }
        *bytes = num;
        for(uint32_t * ptr = bytes+1; ptr < ptr+16; ++ptr){
            //OS throws error 0xC0000005 (accessing unallocated memory) here
            *ptr = 0;
        }
    }
    uint512_t inline operator &(uint512_t &b){
        uint32_t* itera = bytes;
        uint32_t* iterb = b.bytes;
        uint512_t ret(0);
        uint32_t* iterret = ret.bytes;
        for(char i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i){
            *(iterret++) = *(itera++) & *(iterb++);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    uint512_t inline operator =(uint512_t &b){
        uint32_t * itera=bytes, *iterb=b.bytes;
        for(char i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i){
            *(itera++) = *(iterb++);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    uint512_t inline operator + (uint512_t &b){
        uint32_t * itera = bytes;
        uint32_t * iterb = b.bytes;
        uint64_t res = 0;
        uint512_t ret(0);
        uint32_t *p2ret = ret.bytes;
        uint32_t *p2res = 1+(uint32_t*)&res;
        //#pragma omp parallel for shared(p2ret, res, p2res, itera, iterb, ret) private(i, arr_size) schedule(auto)
        for(char i = 0; i < arr_size;++i){
            res = *p2res;
            res += *(itera++);
            res += *(iterb++);
            *(p2ret++) = (i<15) ? res+*(p2res) : res;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    uint512_t inline operator += (uint512_t &b){
        uint32_t * itera = bytes;
        uint32_t * iterb = b.bytes;
        uint64_t res = 0;
        uint512_t ret(0);
        uint32_t *p2ret = ret.bytes;
        uint32_t *p2res = 1+(uint32_t*)&res;
        //#pragma omp parallel for shared(p2ret, res, p2res, itera, iterb, ret) private(i, arr_size) schedule(auto)
        for(char i = 0; i < arr_size;++i){
            res = *p2res;
            res += *(itera++);
            res += *(iterb++);
            *(p2ret++) = (i<15) ? res+(*p2res) : res;
        }
        (*this) = ret;
        return *this;
    }
    //uint512_t inline operator * (uint512_t &b){
    //}
    ~uint512_t(){
        delete[] bytes;
    }
};

int main(void){
    uint512_t a(3);
}
```

Comment: just note: the compiler commands are not formatted because of stackoverflow's terms and conditions for questions - you can't put more code than info - even if the code itself contains tons of info.

Comment: Why do you think  that the compiler wrongfully optimises?

Comment: How do you know it is ignored or optimized away? [Godbolting it](https://godbolt.org/z/7up3zs) shows that `new` is in fact called. For such a small array, I don't see why you're dynamically allocating it anyway. Just use `std::array<uint32_t, 16>`.

Answer (score 5):

The error is at this line and has nothing to do with `new` being optimized away:

```
for(uint32_t * ptr = bytes+1; ptr < ptr+16; ++ptr){
    *ptr = 0;
}
```

The condition for the `for` is wrong. **`ptr < ptr+16` will never be false.** The loop will go on forever and eventually you will dereference an invalid memory location because `ptr` gets incremented ad-infinitum.

---

By the way, the compiler is allowed to perform optimizations but it is not allowed to change the apparent behavior of the program. If your code performs a `new`, the compiler can optimize it away if it can ensure that the side effects of `new` are there when you need them (in this case at the moment you access the array).

Answer (score 5):

`ptr < ptr+16` is always true. The loop is infinite, and eventually overflows the buffer that it writes to.

Simple solution: Value initialise the array so that you don't need the loop:

```
bytes = new(std::nothrow) uint32_t[arr_size]();
//                                          ^^
```

---

PS. If you copy an instance, the behaviour will be undefined, since the copy would point to same allocation and both instances would attempt to delete it in the destructor.

Simple solution: Don't use bare owning pointers. Use a RAII container such as `std::vector` if you need to allocate an array dynamically.

---

PPS. Carefully consider whether you need dynamic allocation (and the associated overhead) in the first place. 512 bits is in many cases a fairly safe size to have in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the array out of bound. The smallest reproducible example would be:

```
#include <cstdint>
int main() {
        uint32_t bytes[16];
        for(uint32_t * ptr = bytes + 1; ptr < ptr + 16; ++ptr){
            //OS throws error 0xC0000005 (accessing unallocated memory) here
            *ptr = 0;
        }
}
```

The `ptr < ptr + 16` is  always true (maybe except for overflow).

Answer (score 0):

p.s i tried your solution, and it worked fine -

```
bytes = new(std::nothrow) uint32_t[arr_size];
    if(!bytes){
        std::cerr << "Error - not enough memory available.";
        exit(-1);
    }
    *bytes = num;
    auto ptrp16 = bytes+16;
    for(uint32_t * ptr = bytes+1;ptr < ptrp16 ; ++ptr){
        *ptr = 0;
    }
```